# How to copy the state of a manually (un)checked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

In other words, without triggering Javascript events to change the attributes of the `<input>`, how to preserve the state of a checkbox that I manually checked or unchecked and then copied to another place?

Run the snippet below and check or uncheck a few of them and hit "copy":

```js
$('#cp').click(function(){
  $('#copy').html($('#original').html())
  $('#copy-clone').html($('#original').clone().html())
})
$('#hi').click(function(){
  $('#original input:checked').parent().css('border','2px solid red')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="original">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="man">man</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="woman">woman</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="monkey">monkey</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="banana" checked="checked">banana</label>
</form>
<button id="cp">copy</button>
<button id="hi">highlight</button>
<br><form id="copy"></form>
<br><form id="copy-clone"></form>
```

Those previously or manually `:checked` are correctly selected, but the states of the manually changed ones is never copied  (run the snippet, select a few, hit "highlight" and then "copy")...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Use `clone(true)` to deep copy the element's data/state ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)).</s>

**Edit per the Andreas' comment:** The `html()` call on the clone is unnecessary.

```js
$('#cp').click(function(){
  $('#copy').html($('#original').clone())
  $('#copy-clone').html($('#original').clone())
})
$('#hi').click(function(){
  $('#original input:checked').parent().css('border','2px solid red')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="original">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="man">man</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="woman">woman</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="monkey">monkey</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="banana" checked="checked">banana</label>
</form>
<button id="cp">copy</button>
<button id="hi">highlight</button>
<br><form id="copy"></form>
<br><form id="copy-clone"></form>
```

Comment: I guess I should have looked better into jquery's clone... Thanks xorspark! But what is that property that defines the state of a checkbox?

Comment: In vanillajs you would look at the `checked` property. In jQuery you can look it up using `prop('checked')`

Comment: The script works but the explanation is wrong. The "fix" here is the missing `.html()` call on the cloned node ! Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpkctrfe/) with `.clone()` and a not working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9k6j5o1d/) with `.clone(true).html()`

Comment: @Andreas oh I see, so there is no need for a deep copy! Since `html()` ignores the manually `:checked` property/attribute, when I did `clone().html()` it ignored the manual interactions (but not the hardcoded property)... Why does it do that?

Comment: Thanks for the catch Andreas. I presume the `html()` method just returns the innerHTML. Checking a checkbox only modifies the internal state but not the HTML content, to take a semi-educated stab at it.

Comment: As xorspark already mentioned, `.html()` internally uses `.innerHTML` which doesn't represent the current state

Comment: I upvoted and I wanted to accept both answers. Since xorspark corrected the usage of clone in my snippet first, thus answering the question (even though he initially thought it was due to the lack of a deep copy), I feel I should accept his answer. I really appreciated the feedback from both of you though.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `.html()` to clone the elements

```js
$('#cp').click(function(){
  var original = $('#original');
  $('#copy').empty().append(original.clone());
  $('#copy-clone').empty().append(original.clone());
})

$('#hi').click(function(){
  $('#original input:checked').parent().css('border','2px solid red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="original">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="man">man</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="woman">woman</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="monkey">monkey</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="banana" checked="checked">banana</label>
</form>
<button id="cp">copy</button>
<button id="hi">highlight</button>
<br><form id="copy"></form>
<br><form id="copy-clone"></form>
```